# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded chrome php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So i have this problem where it says: "jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" and i dont know how to fix it im fixing someones code and here is my php code 
my js

```
function displayCom()
    {
        var com = document.getElementById("sel_cloud").value;
                if (com < 0){
//        throw Exception("Please select a interface")
        }
        else{

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
                url:  "../administration/func_manager/ajax_subscribers.php",
                data: { selInterface: com },
                success: function (data){
                    alert (data);
                    $("#sel_communicator").html(data);
                }
        });
        }
    }
```

and here is my ajax with my select where my dislayCom() function is used:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$current_interface = 'CPANEL';
require_once '../../cao/sys/config.class.php';

if(isset($_POST['selInterface'])){
    $interfaceID = pg_escape_string($_POST['selInterface']) ;

    if($_POST['selInterface'] =='120'){
        $curr_cao = new CGenDb("reddi", '12.121.21.21', 2);
        $curr_cao_tac = new CGenDb("reddi_tac", "12.121.21.21", 2);
    }elseif($_POST['selInterface'] =='121'){
        $curr_cao = new CGenDb("reddi", '212.121.21.21', 12);
        $curr_cao_tac = new CGenDb("database", "212.121.21.21", 12);
    }else{
        echo "no Interface found";
    }

            $query = new CGenRs("SELECT * FROM tac_account ",$curr_cao_tac);
            $query->first();



?>
<div class="row well well-lg">
    <div class="-md-2" >
        <span> communicator </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <select>
            <?php 
            if($query->rowcount()){
                while (!$query->eof() ){
                    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $query->valueof('acc_id'); ?>"><?php echo $query->valueof('acc_name')  ?>  </option>        
            <?php
            $query->next();
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
 <span>Select Interface (required)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" >
                    <select name="sel_cloud" id="sel_cloud" onchange="displayCom()" class="form-control">
                        <option value="-1">Select Interface</option>
                        <?php
                        $sel_interface_options = new CGenRS("select type_desc, type_id from lu_type where type_status = 't' and type_group = 'cloud' and type_sub_group = 'db'", $cao);
                        $sel_interface_options->first();

                        if ($sel_interface_options->rowcount()) {
                            while (!$sel_interface_options->eof()) {
                                ?>
                                <option  value="<?php echo $sel_interface_options->valueof('type_id'); ?>" ><?php echo $sel_interface_options->valueof('type_desc'); ?></option>
                                <?php
                                $sel_interface_options->next();
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br/>
```

Comment: Where do you call `displayCom()`? Maybe you have a infinite loop.

Comment: sorry how could i forget here

Comment: how do i add it

Comment: Edit your post. The link is located at the bottom after your tags.

Comment: i added it like you said

Comment: @Huelfe Where the displayCom() is used is added under the ajax

Comment: Do you have working example code for me? Maybe a link or something?

Comment: im afraid not sorry youll have to need a username and password and i cant give that to you but i got it fixed thanks so much man